# Average number of predators and prey in Lotka–Volterra model?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Once again I wouldn't be surprised if this can be found maybe even on Wikipedia but I'm not a native English speaker and unfortunately couldn't find this myself.

So assuming standard [Lotka–Volterra equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equation), exactly as written in Wikipedia, representing number of prey $x(t)$ and number of predators $y(t)$:

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = x(\alpha - \beta y); \\
\frac{dy}{dt} = - y(\gamma - \delta  x);
$$

I see that the dynamics are very peculiar at least when initial conditions are sufficiently close to non-trivial equilibrium point i.e. we observe a cycle (closed curve on a plane with one axis representing the number of prey and the other axis representing the number of predators).

My question is how to calculate the average number of predators and prey? Where should I apply integration? Maybe even analytical solutions exist in a general case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The average number of prey and predators is given by the coordinates of the nontrivial equilibrium:
$$
\hat{x}=\frac{\gamma}{\delta},\\
\hat{y}=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}.
$$
This can be nicely generalized to the case of ${\bf R}^n$.

To show this just note, e.g., that the first equation can be written as
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\ln x=\alpha-\beta y.
$$
Integrate this from $0$ to $T$ and find that
$$
\frac 1T\int_0^Ty(\tau)d\tau=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}.
$$